# Style nav button with css shap with gradient, gradient background, and centered text

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a nav buttons without using a image. But I can't get the CSS to work out properly. I managed to get everything but the vertical alignment of the text, yet to get that far I feel the code as become more sloppy than necessary. Here is what I have:

```css
.nav_button {
  height: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(#3D3C3B 0%, #0A0B0A 50%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
}

.nav_arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(#D2DA76 0%, #5EB649 50%);
}

.nav_link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_arrow::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #D2DA76 0%, #5EB649 50%);
  transform: translate(10px, 0px) scale(.8, .715) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>
  <div class='nav_button'><span class='arrow_container'><div class='nav_arrow'></div></span><span class='nav_link'>Test</span></div>
</a>
```

Is there a better way to write this? if not I at least need to know how to vertical align the text. line-height did not work.

Edit: Here is a demo pic. the arrow is backwards but it's close.

[image: demo]

Comment: Could you provide an image of what your end result is intending to look like?

Comment: @haxxxton ok. I added a pic. as i said the only thing I haven't solved yet is vertical align of the text. though i feel all the nested div is spans in the html is a sloppy code.

Comment: Could be written a lot cleaner, but you're looking for `vertical-align:middle` or `line-height: px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution may be to actually build your button's structure relative to the size of the text's line-height, rather than trying to hardcode the size and then update the line-height secondly.

The simplification of the html is based upon the idea that we use a single gradient overlay on the button rather than fading both the button background *and* the "arrow" section with different colours independently. However, this doesnt *exactly* match the design.

```css
.nav_button_alt{
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #888;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 position:relative;
 background:#5EB649;
 font-size:1.2em;
 line-height:1.4em;
 padding:0 0.2em 0 40px;
 min-width:125px; /* remove this if you wish the buttons to be relative to the size of the text*/
}
.nav_button_alt > span{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 z-index:3;
  text-align:center;
}
/* provides the fade */
.nav_button_alt:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index:2;
 height:100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%); 
}
/* provides the "black" overlay of the green background */
.nav_button_alt:after{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 left:1.2em; /* distance from the right that the arrow starts */
 top:0;
 height:0;
 right:0;
 border-left:1em solid transparent; /* size of the green arrow's point */
 border-top:0.7em solid #000; /* half the height of the button */
 border-bottom:0.7em solid #000; /* half the height of the button */
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav_button_alt">
 <span>Test</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Ahh so close. looks great but I need the arrow on the left side and the text center  after the arrow. I do much better with back end code like php, front end design is not my strong point. could you tell me how to flip the arrow and center the text? thanks!

Comment: @Zaper127, updated. It's a whole different world :) Definitely no judgement here

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks man. I spend all day just to get to where I was. CSS3 has so many cool new features. Wish i had the skill to use them lol.

Comment: @Zaper127, you're welcome, please consider marking an answer as the solution.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try vertically aligning the text inside the button.

```css
.nav_button {
  height: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(#3D3C3B 0%, #0A0B0A 50%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
}

.nav_arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(#D2DA76 0%, #5EB649 50%);
}

.nav_link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.nav_arrow::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #D2DA76 0%, #5EB649 50%);
  transform: translate(10px, 0px) scale(.8, .715) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>
  <div class='nav_button'><span class='arrow_container'><div class='nav_arrow'></div></span><span class='nav_link'>Test</span></div>
</a>
```

Comment: hmm. I tried vertical-align: middle;, never thought about top. it worked, thank you. could you explain why middle doesn't work but top aligns it in the middle?

Comment: By default, it will align baseline of .nav_link to the baseline of its parent element. Setting vertical align top will cause the top of the element to be aligned with the top of the tallest element on the line.

Comment: Vertical align middle will cause the element to be aligned at the middle of its parent container, causing it to start only from the middle.You may play with this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=middle

Answer (score 0):

Use "line-height" for vertical alignment of text. Here's an example

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World!
</div>
```